# Facing issue with proxmox noVNC (API), Error 401 no ticket

Tags: vnc, proxmox

I am new to proxmox, 
I'm trying to run noVNC using php. I authenticate Using API_URL/access/ticket and set ticket to cookie "PVEAuthCookie"

I have tried to connect in the following way
https://domain:8006/?console=kvm&novnc=1&vmid=100&vmname=name&node=namenode

The error shown is "Error 401: No ticket"
[image]

It's work when I have logged in to the web of the proxmox service, and I tried to set cookie with domain of the proxmox, but i Can't set due to browser security.

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need erase cookie for you proxmox server. It help for you.

It may also be a problem with the time, check date on the proxmox and local PC.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Time is same. Also i tried with erase cookie.

Answer (score 0):

To fix

> Error 401: No ticket'

you will need to empty the client browsers cache.